# Sin function without using math.h library

Tags: c, calculator

I've got an assignment for FOP to make a scientific calculator, we haven't been taught about the math.h library! my basic approach for one of the function SIN was this
but i'm failing to make this work

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int input;
float pi;
double degree;
double sinx;
long int powerseven;
long int powerfive;
long int powerthree;
input = 5;
degree= (input*pi)/180;
pi=3.142;
powerseven=(degree*degree*degree*degree*degree*degree*degree);
powerfive=(degree*degree*degree*degree*degree);
powerthree=(degree*degree*degree);
sinx = (degree - (powerthree/6) + (powerfive/120) - (powerseven/5040));
printf("%ld", sinx);
getchar();
}
```

Comment: Explain why you are `failing to make this work`, tell us what is wrong so we can help you.

Comment: Your equation is for radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code almost works.  You have a few problems:

1. You are using `pi` before initializing it.  I suggest using a more accurate value of `pi` such as `3.14159265359`.
2. `powerseven`, `powerfive` and `powerthree` should be defined as `double` instead of as `long int`.  You are losing precision by storing these values in an integer type.  Also, when you divide an integer value by an integer value (such as `powerthree/6`) the remainder is lost.  For instance, `9/6` is `1`.
3. Since `sinx` is a `double` you should be using `printf("%f", sinx);`

Comment: Since OP is using `double` and `double` typically has 15+ decimal digits of precision, rather than going from 3 digits to 12 digits, offer a matching length (or longer) pi.  Extras digits will not hurt. e.g. 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

Comment: @vacawama +1 for patience

Comment: @vacawama its working now :D thankyou for the help. new to this website and field

Answer (score 3):

vacawama covered most of the technical C-language reasons your program isn't working. I'll attempt to cover some algorithmic ones. Using a fixed finite number of taylor series terms to compute sine is going to lose precision quickly as the argument gets farther away from the point at which you did the series expansion, i.e. zero.

To avoid this problem, you want to use the periodicity of the sine function to reduce your argument to a bounded interval. If your input is in radians, this is actually a difficult problem in itself, since pi is not representable in floating point. But as long as you're working in degrees, you can perform argument reduction by repeatedly subtracting the greatest power-of-two multiple of 360 that's less than the argument, until your result is in the interval [0,360). (If you could use the standard library, you could just use `fmod` for this.)

Once your argument is in a bounded interval, you can just choose an approximation that's sufficiently precise on that interval. A taylor series approximation is certainly one approach you can use at this point, but not the only one.